# Why does parseBoolean not throw an exception?

Tags: java, parsing, exception

Considering

```
boolean b = Boolean.parseBoolean("100");
```

I thought it would throw an exception because `"100"` is neither `"true"` nor `"false"`. But it passed, no exceptions.

Why does the method not throw?

Comment: Why do you expect it to throw an exception? The javadoc does not mention any.

Comment: Thanks! Didnt check Jabvadoc

Comment: I like the question but you are really expected to read docs before posting, "show research effort". Hence the downvotes. See [ask], thaks.

Comment: Okay. Thanks Zabuza

Comment: It is a questionable design choice though, I suspect more people could be confused by that. So the question is definitly helpful to the SO community.

Comment: Thanks for the meaningful edit Zabuza. Those were my exact thoughts.

Comment: Came here to confirm if the method can throw exceptions. Agreed that it's a good (and imo underrated) question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reading the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#parseBoolean-java.lang.String-) of the method (emphasis mine):

> Parses the string argument as a boolean.  The boolean returned represents the value `true` if the string argument is not `null` and is equal, ignoring case, to the string `"true"`.
>   **Otherwise, a false value is returned**, including for a null argument.

Looking at the [implementation](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/tip/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Boolean.java#l131):

```java
    public static boolean parseBoolean(String s) {
        return "true".equalsIgnoreCase(s);
    }
```

So anything not equal to the String `"true"` – ignoring case – is considered to be `false`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation knittl.

Comment: @knittl Do you know why it was implemented that way and not via if s.equals(true) return true / else if  s.equals(false) return false / else throws an exception? The implementation is so misleading

Comment: @swaechter no, I don't know. One reason might be "null-safety", because `s.equals("true")` will throw an NPE for null inputs. Also, you'd probably want "true", "True" and "TRUE" all to be parsed as `true`. That leaves anything else to be `false`.